# How Show A Captcha Image In A picturebox Before Login? (HTTPWebRequest)

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, captcha, picturebox

please see the codes below :

```
    getData = "";
    txtLog.Text += "req 5";
    txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";
    txtLog.Text += "getData = " + getData;
    txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

    HttpWebRequest req5 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
    req5.Method = "GET";
    req5.Accept = "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5";
    req5.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0";
    req5.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    //req5.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    req5.Referer = location_from_req_2;
    req5.KeepAlive = true;
    //req5.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    req5.Timeout = TimeOut;

    req5.Proxy = proxy;

    cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    req5.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

    res = (HttpWebResponse)req5.GetResponse();
    txtLog.Text += ((HttpWebResponse)res).StatusDescription;
    txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

    //string[] cookies = res.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
    //string[] cookies_ = cookies;

    if (res.Cookies != null && res.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        cookieJar.Add(res.Cookies);
    }
    foreach (Cookie cookie in res.Cookies)
    {
        cookieJar.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), "/", cookie.Domain));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Headers["Set-Cookie"]))
    {
        ArrayList al = ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(res.Headers["Set-Cookie"]);
        CookieCollection cc = ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(al, "empty.com");
        cookieJar.Add(cc);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cookieJar.GetCookies(req5.RequestUri).Count; i++)
    {
        Cookie cookie = cookieJar.GetCookies(req5.RequestUri)[i];
        txtLog.Text += "#" + (i + 1).ToString() + "; name: " + cookie.Name.ToString() + "; value: " + cookie.Value.ToString() + "; path: " + cookie.Path.ToString() + "; domain: " + cookie.Domain.ToString() + "; version: " + cookie.Version.ToString();
        txtLog.Text += "\r\n++++++++++++++++++\r\n";
    }
    txtLog.Text += "cookieJar Count: " + cookieJar.Count.ToString() + "; req 5: " + req5.RequestUri;
    txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

    //string location_from_req_5 = res.Headers["Location"];

    Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
    reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    txtLog.Text += reader_str;
    txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

    var image = Image.FromStream(Stream);
    imgCaptcha.Image = image;

    reader.Close();
    Stream.Close();
    res.Close();
```

i am using visual studio 2010 (.net 4) and a windows form application.
i want to show the goal web site's captcha image in my picturebox!
i now CookieContainer is an important part of my codes and i think it works.
the reader_str string afetr these codes is like this :

```
"����\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0��\0C\0\a\a\a\a\a\a\b\t\v\t\b\b\n\b\a\a\n\r\n\n\v\f\f\f\f\a\t\r\f\v\f\f\f��\0C\f\b\a\b\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f\f��\0\b\00\0�\"\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\b\t\n\v��\0�\0\0\0}\0!1AQa\a\"q2���\b#B��R��$3br�\t\n%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\b\t\n\v��\0�\0\a\0w\0!1AQ\aaq\"2�\bB����\t#3R�br�\n$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������\0\f\0\0?\0����z��੿�\0��6�|i�5MZٮ��#es<�Ȥ��c��r\b�������9��~)y����6�N#����Ig?�#�\a��a2,~&ҍ&��e��#9U�vl�I��$�࿟���������ĳ���ƥ��`����c�\0��5O�<���s�����,�����\t<M*0p�X6m�R\b���W�G��j�T����᧯�C��[��ފ���������g�w��fWN������%�y�\n\f��{u=�����\0��\v������!ռ!�spmm��t��&���!q1f�l'�y��\fu9(�s7} �ޝ�[�j�^��TW�|\0���~�:����#Ŗ:���6�CM�)l����K�N�*�ܣq\\d��קוV��˒�Z}��i��\n(��QE\0Q\\w��\0�>��>k�9�o�x���ss<���rF]�\0w&�)u�;����c\a�>|��\0�u��6VwQE]���d���%p\a\\W��dx�t\\�ܒ����\b�H�I3�.�����\n��k_C$��\"���Y|i1F��J����^���F�i����~=��<�\n�G��-}�]k�i�w�zF��4p6�wʫ�\f`涫�غpu$�e��A�\nM��E�~����������U�?���i��<\t���qx����E��+x�9S��/�\\��q_n�c>?�oW�\0�zk�?�O�k⟇֖��Z�����������%ěv�-�0'�]X��P�F�f�{k5v�'d�����Ŧ�C������\0ি���\0���\a����x���:�x���nƊ�Q$�o춬�\t%�Y�_`�g���A���> �������&���y��fז�̫\"�++ಲ�#�\"��VU��+5̮�㪺�u��ٗ�z���?���U:ť���:���-u�y���+�G�uV�q_[��K�8ʺ0ea�EpJ�ĬU�(����TwQZ�2�a��'Ӛ\0��˳�Ƌ�^���X���Sʎ�6}è�9ȭJm5�_����<E���*���GHV[9�\v4�h�p �c�[>�g�G�C����/���V��\0Q[tU��q�rv�qY_�_�ٴ~�_�Uϊz5���ӵ����3��ݠ���S'�_�-?��z�����o��--�H�;{�\rj2*��,�����d�_u��;�f�Ž*E���~O�9���;�?g?��������G���\0\b�2���K�tY\t>��f�;?��/�{�?�T_ؗ�>\"0��_�b����ݦX����QU��g\\(��9�g�\0�[~4���\0�>�\"�IVK�j�� ݖEI�����q�+���8w�������\0f��.�[���/�+mWŒ[٬��������(���v5�S�ts��{ih��i%����r�$�\r�[�7�?k��/��o�ˋ��Xx7J���ѭ,E�4�mnF�),\0\f������ۃ����/��_נ��5�v�=�^�S��<E��q�\t�NY�\b��x\a�����\0�+?j}+���=�]k߳7��x�G�`�����Pħh*�H\v�s�\a����)����\n'�\0\a^Z|4I���:�ᛝt�3��[�������9�`�v��llC �_-�.t�ˊTޭ�׋�2}���|:�D�������,������\0�Z���I�Z����B�;�\tqt�~�*�\0H���O�G��e�\v����7�k=N)~x�Ņ���F��O2�:��3G&\b9�>1�|K�Z~�_�������D�\0~(��\0��O�N��\v[\0Ύ9 Tj�T�Tt!���T��e�7���\0���\0j����������P��m�Oi��̼�.4�w����$�!b\n��ҹ�IQB�t�QT��ȴ��ck4�k]^������mm��o��\0<7�W��%�f��xB��i��ofE��<��\0�2N8�߳���O�Wo�O�_�^�g��d��.�I\r��)��2��#���W�^�\0�n|g�\0��x���w�q{��+�dR\v�\r�&�.�^���w�#vA;Ԝ�*���#g�!�*���.��+�Yxx|��m<\v{{�\0�yd\t�7$�9&�\\N���Rnu:�ۖ>W��4��-R��o?��_�-v��\0$���~\\_��~�1�\fQ���*ײ�IPA�\ankS�\b�����:��O������O��6z�%�M&6�gftČ2�m8\a 濡�\n�����Ý>�Y|%�Wm� 73xz��\\t���\\�rs^���l����cL�!0¡~�����a�Y�^%M���7��'�_�c��?<����?�t����66�#����\t���%��<0--ѻ��0�@�#'ھ����/����?\r�v:焥�����-_tR]���\a�2+���}�\0����?�\0dK��^����'jڍ����R;���Pҗ�|�̣`O�O����m��⿃��Hm3�,.�ƷZ���tYd�Ӯ�UU��w�gǤ���32ɰ���(J���yd�u�h��*I���>\v�\0�O<-'�3�\0\t���0kQG�G{a43���<�����Cg ��`+��\0��/��\0?e?���/�� x�iQ��2ŧ�A&��r�\0�L0��z�d�'��/� o��V�i����_ǞL��X�c���\v��\"�y�VV\fv`�\a95�M��o���U߆��M��\r<ۄ�uI���E��l�X'����3,���ӓ���Z�������;y38Sn�#��{��\0�i��X��>j~!Ҽu�_�/Xo��#����,��`�\r�+�A�PA�p�\0�RO�6�?�e\t�|�um/�?\v��4�,jw���->�=���Ƞ$�$��W�T��?KeO��/�[�p������v�O&�ڬ�i�-ʨKa'�tM�\r#3���c���e�x��[\bҳ�����Y/GceE8�G��\r�0~�З��׾(�b���a�Y�5͌���[ʫ̌q�0$\r��_��<x���g��;���ĝw�vZ��n�r��ߝ�D����7�_\0z���?�����\0�s����#Q��m�Y�~�\r�m\r���Y��2��\b�U\nŔ4��k���\b��#|Uмy�~Ӛ7��ߍ^��mF��\v뫿/+4�w�X� ��dg��fq����Ww[(I��ݔ��z%Ͷ��qV�������#����A|�\0�{�?�yw�o�݊^h��A��1����w�`\\�1\a�����(O�o�\0N���gy.��熴x����\b��]鷧�$�Ӆ�����������I���\0��K�\v�F��͠jV���h�9���X�pT`���?�,�ů��/���?b���#��Q���a��CÐ>���U�b>�Z����6�R�IyE�o���U �R�h�1�?�������Oҿh���+����������\a���\v�;z�=+��0�\0�p��M���?l��k��u_L���lW�\05����?\r�C������>��ʞ\rg��a�_�e#����������ǃM���=j���Z��2K\a�����8r;a�v���b�5�}�tW�:p���S�+y'�s�aO�&��\0\v����_���^�i�~8y���1��<RIv�xۑ�#\"�I����e�\0����U�I<'�\a�v��o٧�t�W�{��\\\b�h��\0I�9��M�Ԃ\0�s���k㸯���n����;9C�ٵ�%t�QE��_�\0�������kǩcm%ֱ�-�OeQ%��|J�\a<�$��\0�_{Q]�~2XLM<L7�O�{|ɔy�L�R�\0�6�x3�_�Ox�@�4�(�+wO����F�'�eV`lE\t�\\��KZD�I�2I�%FMIEt�Y���6x�^^ki{�K˰�Ò*#Zd\nQJ��q_�_�����'���\0d����g��x�/iˢ���R�XMq���Ͷv\v�M~��X���L$�($ԓ�Of�����c��>4���<o�z���~$|k�ŧ�<#���\fx%� ���VeU��ۼ�2E�1$oԒ�\b��O� .��1~Ԟ4���+�Q�J�%��5\rs¶�#5�����s\\yn��8��i���г�\\iʍ)r�J�]�ݓwz���R}�ove�������z��oq�O��Mi�m�:�xܤ�{�_�zG���?\v��G���\0h�.�{��m�,J��'XOZ�8���f��\"q�+'�����\b�s�X�\0�u�]�*k_����5+)�\t��H�ܫ1k�_�k�Ǳ�!���ĩIɞ�[��v�\")����cEw�ٟ/,j���'�ñ����\0\a���\0e��\r�4���-�����̚���NVH��X��8e ��%T\"�\0\0p\0�KEyx�n#.|D��v��ˌTtH(���((��\0��\vi�6��擬X��zf�\v[�Z��$�x�a���A�+�\a�?\b~����>\a�։�?[I$��U�Z���Ŝ�h��I⺊*�Ir�_N��*�P\0\0@�\f▊�#��.<�(p�H��RQE�EP�\0\0=-P\a��\r\n\r\n"
```

i think this is our image and now i want to show it in my picturebox.
but i always have error in this line -> `var image = Image.FromStream(Stream);`
and that error -> `Parameter is not valid.`
what is going on and what is the problem!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're reading out the data from the stream and forgetting to reset it to the beginning. Just don't read out the data into a string, and you should be fine.

```
Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
//reader = new StreamReader(Stream); <-- Don't do these 4 lines
//reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();
//txtLog.Text += reader_str;
//txtLog.Text += "\r\n----------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

var image = Image.FromStream(Stream);
```

If you want to keep the lines, you just have to reset the stream back to the beginning, using:

```
Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: you were right dude, really thanks. i was working some hours on it for finding the problem. but what was the problem of those lines? how can i keep them?

Comment: besides i test -> Stream.Position = 0; after commented lines. but this line has error too. would you please give us some note about that!

Comment: @MoonLight What do you mean you test `Stream.Position = 0`? And I'm not a sir, but you're welcome.

Comment: i have this error after your edit -> This stream does not support seek operations. mean this line -> Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  also Stream.Position = 0; has an error like that.

Comment: Ah. Well, if it says that, then you probably can't remove the data twice. Sorry. :(